# Java: How to display card JPanel fully when using CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, applet, layout-manager, cardlayout

I'm having trouble with this `JApplet`. At the moment I have a `CardLayout` `JPanel` which contains two `BorderLayout` `JPanel`s. Whenever I run it, the components added to each 'card' (a `JButton` to go back to the other `JPanel`) don't display unless I use `setVisible(true)` for each `LayoutManager`. Furthermore, none of my `ActionListener`s work. I'm assuming because they only use `show()` and there's something else I have to do that's alluding me.

Must I use `setVisible(true)`? It seems from other questions that there's a way of doing this without that. Here's the code I'm having trouble with:

```
/*
*Java Version:      1.8.0_25
*Author:            Peadar Ó Duinnín
*Student Number:    R00095488
*/

package As1;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class AUIJApplet extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    private final int WIDTH = 600;
    private final int HEIGHT = 400;
    private int highScore;
    private int currentScore;

    JPanel panelCont = new JPanel();
    JPanel startPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
    JButton newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
    JButton endGameButton = new JButton("End Game");
    JLabel highScoreLabel;
    JLabel currentScoreLabel;
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();

    public AUIJApplet() {
        highScore = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        panelCont.setLayout(cl);
        startPanel.setLayout(bl);
        gamePanel.setLayout(bl);

        startPanel.add(newGameButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        gamePanel.add(endGameButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        startPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        gamePanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        panelCont.add(startPanel, "Start Applet Screen");
        panelCont.add(gamePanel, "New Game Screen");

        newGameButton.addActionListener((e) -> {
            newGame();
        });

        endGameButton.addActionListener((e) -> {
            quitGame();
        });

        cl.show(panelCont, "Start Applet Screen");
        this.add(panelCont);
    }

    public void newGame() {
        cl.show(panelCont, "New Game Screen");
        showScores(gamePanel);
    }

    public void quitGame() {
        cl.show(panelCont, "Start Applet Screen");
        if (currentScore > highScore) {
            highScore = currentScore;
        }
        currentScore = 0;
    }

    public void showScores(JPanel currentPanel) {
        currentPanel.add(new JLabel("High Score:") , BorderLayout.EAST);
        currentPanel.add(highScoreLabel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        currentPanel.add(new JLabel("Current Score:"), BorderLayout.EAST);
        currentPanel.add(currentScoreLabel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You should check first how `cardlayout` works http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Comment: I have. I've also used Java The Complete Reference 8th Ed. by Herbert Schildt and as far as I can see, I'm doing everything how I should be doing it. If it's just a small thing, I'd appreciate some help with it. If it looks like I'm doing it all wrong, just say and I'll scrap it and try from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made the a little similar code to perform same operation it works for me try to write the code from scratch. Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.*;


    public class Example extends JApplet {

        JPanel panel1,panel2,mainPanel;
        JButton start,stop;
        CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
        @Override
        public void init() {
            panel1 = new JPanel();
            panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
            panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            panel2 = new JPanel();
            panel2.setBackground(Color.blue);
            panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            start = new JButton("Start");
            stop = new JButton("stop");
            panel1.add(start,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            panel2.add(stop,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            mainPanel = new JPanel();
            mainPanel.setLayout(cl);
            mainPanel.add(panel1,"First Panel");
            mainPanel.add(panel2, "Second Panel");
            start.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                newGame();
            });
            stop.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) ->{
                endGame();
            });
            this.add(mainPanel);
        }

        public void newGame()
        {
            cl.show(mainPanel, "Second Panel");
        }
        public void endGame()
        {
            cl.show(mainPanel,"First Panel");
        }
    }
```